# How to accept MultipartFile in Spring Integration's inbound gateway

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-integration

I want to accept file using inbound-gateway.
With regular Spring Boot it is pretty easy

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, path = "/upload/{configurationUid}", consumes = {"multipart/form-data"})
public void create(@RequestPart("file") MultipartFile file,@PathVariable String configurationUid){}
```

How to do the same with Spring Integration integration.xml? ASAIK, Spring Integration supports it but it is absolutely not clear for me how to write the appropriate inbound-gateway

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is so easy with Spring Integration as well.

You just need to configure `new HttpRequestHandlingMessagingGateway()` with an appropriate `RequestMethod.POST`, `path`. There is also `RequestMapping` object to accept `consumes` property.

The most important part is a `multipartResolver` bean, but it is already configured by Spring Boot via `MultipartAutoConfiguration`.

More info is in the [Reference Manual](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.0.RELEASE/reference/html/http.html#multipart-rest-inbound) and mentioned there [HTTP Sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/intermediate/multipart-http).